# POI created excel file, date delimiter changed based on client date format

Tags: excel, apache-poi

After creating a workbook using the `poi-ooxml` package to set a date cell style/format as `mm/dd/yyyy`, it displayed as `mm-dd-yyyy` format when I open it. However when I change then system's short date format as 'yyyy/mm/dd', the cell is displayed correctly as the desired format - `mm/dd/yyyy`. So I wonder how can I set the cell format to `mm/dd/yyyy` using `/` as the delimiter, and not be discriminated by client machines?

[image]

Codes to set the cell style

```java
val dateCell = row.createCell(2);
// dateOccurred is LocalDate type
val date = DateUtil.getExcelDate(record.getDateOccurred()); 
dateCell.setCellValue(date);
val cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
val format = wb.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: What code are you using the set the style?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have attached the code which set the cell style. Let me know if you'd like more context

Answer (score 4):

`Excel`'s default date delimiter is determined by the client system settings. And the `Excel` number format `mm/dd/yyyy` means: Two digits month, followed by default date delimiter, followed by two digits day, followed by default  date delimiter, followed by four digits year. So it is normal that the slash as the default date delimiter gets replaced by the system's default  date delimiter.

You can avoid this by using the text `/` between the date parts instead of the default date delimiter slash. To mark a character which has special meaning as text in `Excel` number formats, the character can prefixed by a backslash `\`.

So

```
cellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("mm\\/dd\\/yyyy"));
```

will always format the date using a slash as the text `/` between the date parts independent of the client's settings.

Comment: This format works fine! I was so close to this, don't know why I didn't try this pattern. Thanks a lot! And I guessed that Excel 'translates' `/` as `short date delimiter` but don't know how to verify this thought.

Comment: @YufengGuo Landed on the same issue. Did you happen to find out how to verify this. I also tried POI's DateFormatConverter, but was no help.

Comment: @DKG: You cannot determine the default date delimiter of the operating system the Excel runs in using Apache POI. Apache POI does not interact with the Excel application nor with the operating system the Excel runs in.